# Creating a Rails 3 named scope involving 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Running Rails 3.0.7 on Mac OS X with Ruby 1.9.2

I have three models with tables behind them (sqlite3 for dev, postgres for prod). They are as follows (validations and other irrelevant lines truncated):

```
class ServiceProvider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services
  has_many :advertisements, :through => :services
  scope :active, where("service_providers.active = ?", true)
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_provider
  has_many :advertisements
  scope :active, joins(:service_provider).where("services.active = ?", true) & ServiceProvider.active
end

class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  scope :ranked, where("advertisements.rank > 0")
  scope :current, where("start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today)
  scope :service_active, joins(:service) & Service.active
  scope :active, ranked.current.service_active
end
```

As you can see, each service provider has many services and each service can have many advertisements. The advertisements table has the service_id foreign key in it and the services table has the service_provider_id foreign key in it. All pretty standard many to one relationships. Service Providers can be made inactive through an "active" flag as can individual services in a similar way.

What I want to be able to do is create a named scope on the Advertisement model to give me a list of all advertisements which are ranked and current and who's parent service is active and in turn who's service_provider is active. In other words, if a service is made inactive then all advertisements pointing to it should become inactive and if a service provider is made inactive then all services, and in turn all advertisements under those services should become inactive.

I have made a stab at creating the required named scopes above and it works as expected at the Service.active and ServiceProvider.active levels but if I type in Advertisement.active I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'service_provider' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

I think this is because I don't have service_provider_id as a foreign key field in the advertisers table but I didn't think I would need that because it should access the service_provider via the service_provider_id field on the services table. It feels like I need a belongs_to :service_provider, :through => :service clause in my Advertisement model but this isn't possible as far as I know. I have tried various things to get this working but I'm struggling to make progress.

Can anyone tell me a nice elegant way to achieve the above, ideally without changing my table structure? I need it to be quite efficient as this query will be run for every page load on my website (sidebar ads on each page).

Many thanks,
Craig.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following would work:

```
class Advertisement
    scope :service_active, joins(:service => :service_provider)
                           .where(:services => { :active => true })
                           .where(:service_providers => { :active => true })
end
```

Then you should be able to call

```
Advertisement.ranked.current.service_active
```

and get the expected result.

Comment: That works great, thanks! A beautifully elegant solution too which was exactly what I was looking for. Rails never ceases to amaze me. I did a lot of searching today and never found the syntax you have used. Definitely one for the toolbox! Thanks for your time!